# OS login password: How does it work?

Tags: authentication, operating-systems, salt

I am making an application to create a password for a user. I am a bit baffled over how it all works though. Namely I want to be sure that my application will store the correct hash so the user can actually login!

I found this code:

```
pwhash=$(echo $password | mkpasswd -s -m sha-512)
```

Now if I run the same password I get two totally different hashes:

```
$ echo 'test' | mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
$6$QRsW.mu9wC$CSvMrGkfU6.lu14.sNRrZ8Kiyi0zUdlcAH1VBBd.LoTZDmehuoGnsaywm/WD.9GARwINQnp3jJzxQHWlCk3RI0
$ echo 'test' | mkpasswd -s -m sha-512
$6$rN7ishjxd89AjMS$HpN53OoL3m81rPyrKFgpm2Nm2YWJ96nP4gNLu4GO0Jjy9K6lVhB6v7c0L7/998h74oTMGFzLK6w4zku7U3soW0
```

So this to me shows just how little I know. If the same password generates two different hashes, how can the OS know that I entered the right password in the login screen? What will it compare the entered password hash with?

Also a bit about salt.. the salt is supposed to always be different, so how can the OS know what salt to use for the password at every login attempt?

Comment: It depends on the OS : what is the one that concerns you?

Comment: @begueradj I use Ubuntu..

Comment: The salt is supposed to be random, but not supposed to be private. It's needed to prevent rainbow tables or similar attacks to be used against the stored password. The OS knows the salt because it's simply appended to the final hashed password (or stored in a different place). Here more info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187333/why-mkpasswd-m-sha-512-produce-different-result-every-time-it-is-called  . For example your last salt is rN7ishjxd89AjMS and as you can see here https://quickhash.com/ if you encrypt "test" with that salt it produces the same output

Comment: @SebastianoRoncato: Why not put your comment in an answer? This seems to me to fully answer the OP question, even giving a practical way to check your assertion. I do not see what more could be added :).

Comment: @SebastianoRoncato I thought the point with the salt is to be hashed **with** the password. Else what's the point? Anyone can just cut out the salt from the final hash..

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf I was from mobile and didn't have time to formulate and format a complete answer, so I preferred to post as a comment

Answer (score 1):

You get different values because different salts are used. The salt is the [second field](http://www.slashroot.in/how-are-passwords-stored-linux-understanding-hashing-shadow-utils) in the hashed password.

There exist large [rainbow tables](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=rainbow%20table&es_th=1) that make the lookup of hashes of common passwords very cheap. The point of salt is to dramatically increase the cost of precalculating hashes for all commonly used passwords. So salt basically makes a password uncommon. That is, it makes a password so long and random that it is unfeasible to precalculate the hash for all common passwords **for all possible salts**.

Given that the goal of salt is to prevent successful precalculation attacks, it doesn't need to be a secret, it just needs to be long and random. This allows the salt to be stored in clear-text along with each hashed password. This is fortunate as the salt is needed to validate the password when the user authenticates.

An example of a bad implementation of salt would be to use a single byte. In that scenario an attacker could precalculate all hashes for common passwords for the 256 possible salts. That is expensive but not expensive enough. That salt isn't large enough.

Another example of mis-salting is to use the same salt on every password. That allows an attacker to precalculate a single table that contains the hashes of all common passwords for that one salt. This would be expensive but much cheaper than having to create a table for each password. That's why each password hash has its own salt.

**Edit:** Salting does not reduce the cost of brute-forcing a single password. Salting just forces you to brute-force passwords instead of precomputing their hashes. You protect against brute-forcing by using a slow hash function and calling it many times on successive output of itself. For example, running bcrypt (which is designed to be slow even with a GPU or other specialized hardware) 1024 times. While PHP stores the number of iterations in the [password field](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.password.storing-salts), on Linux the number of iterations is configured by the [PAM 'rounds'](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_unix.html) option. Several users [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=60679#p354073) say that the default for their Debian Linux install is 1000 iterations for SHA-512.

Of course, no answer about passwords is complete without a reference to [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/10885), a detailed explanation about the state of the art for password storage.

Comment: I still don't get it. If the salt is in clear text then the attacker can just do `sha512(guessingpwd + salt)` and compare it with the hash in the pwd file. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohanHanssenSeferidis - see updated answer - basically, you are correct - salt is a protection against precomputation - algorithm repetition is what's used to protect against brute-forcing